# How to set the default download file name of an dynamically created <audio> element?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, download

when the source of the audio element is dynamically obtained from a blob `new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob))` and that audio is downloaded from the default download button (in the three dots menu), the name of the downloaded file becomes `415fa035-08ba-4a67-ae0d-a0d6876a1eef.txt` even if I set `type="audio/wav"` or `download="file.wav"`.

```
<audio preload="auto" src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:5500/415fa035-08ba-4a67-ae0d-a0d6876a1eef" controls="true" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

how to manually set the name of the file downloaded from an audio element dynamically created this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download file name can be set by setting the title attribute of the element.

```
<audio preload="auto" src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:5500/415fa035-08ba-4a67-ae0d-a0d6876a1eef" controls="true" type="audio/wav" title="file.wav"></audio>
```

or

```
audioElement.title = "file.wav"
```

now the file is saved with this name and extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when working on HTML audio tags.

The solution is simple. All you need to do is to set the audio title attribute to the name and extension you would want your download link to have.

for example

audio.title = "myLovelySong.mp3"

Now your download name will have myLovelySong.mp3.